# Android: Storing text file in android device's internal memory not in external memory card?

Tags: android, local-storage, environment

I tried to store text file in phone memory of the device, It was working with which device support external slot., but it is not working with android phone which doesn't have external slot.( For Example Samsung S6 Edge).

Here is my Code:

```
public void AfterSaveClick() {

        OutputStream fOut = null;

        try {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Start",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //device basic path(phone memory)
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "Log_Folder" + File.separator);
            root.mkdirs();
            File phoneMemoryTextMainDirectory = new File(root, "samples.txt");

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(phoneMemoryTextMainDirectory);
            writer.append("Hello");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you are using the right code... Are there any exceptions thrown? *Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage* -- [`getExternalStorageDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

Comment: What Exception are you getting ?

Comment: i'm not getting any Exception, sample.txt file is stored all device except S6 Edge, MotoG (Which doesn't support sd cards)

Comment: and Even if the doesn't have sdcard in other device(Such as Samsung, Lenovo,etc) - file was storing in phone memory. Why? How? here is my confusion.. :(

Comment: Replace your "root" by "/mnt/sdcard/Log_Folder" along with your filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you should do is check first if the device has external storage, you can use something like this:

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
```

if the device has external storage then use the path that you already have, otherwise you should add another path inside the phone's internal memory.